# Instantiate an inner class inherited with protected access specifier

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes

I wanted to make the following exercise from Bruce Eckel's TIJ on inner classes:

```
Create an interface with at least one method, in its own package.
Create a class in a separate package. Add a protected inner class
that implements the interface. In a third package, inherit from
your class and, inside a method, return an object of the protected
inner class, upcasting to the interface during the return.
```

Here's my implementation:

first, the interface:

```
package workers;

public interface Employable {
  void work();
}
```

then, a class with an inner class implementing the interface:

```
package second;

import workers.Employable;

public class WorkersClass {
    protected class Worker implements Employable {
        @Override
        public void work() {
            System.out.println("Hello, I'm a worker!");
        }
    }
}
```

and finally the inherited class:

```
package third;

import second.WorkersClass;
import workers.Employable;

public class Third extends WorkersClass {
    Employable getWorker() {
        return new Worker();//the line is reported to be incorrect
    }
}
```

IDEA underlines the line with `Worker()` in `getWorker` and suggests to make the `Worker` class `public`. But why? It's protected that's why successors of `WorkersClass` can instantiate the `Worker` class in their methods. Do I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem is not all with access specifier.**

*When you don't provide any constructor in a class, the compiler automatically inserts a default, no-args constructor for you*

That's not true here in this case. Because the compiled inner class doesn't get the default constructor since it gets compiled as `outer$inner` and for that `inner` there is no default constructor provided by compiler.

Provide a default `no org constructor` manually and see the magic :)

```
package second;

import workers.Employable;

public class WorkersClass {
    protected class Worker implements Employable {


        public Worker() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void work() {
            System.out.println("Hello, I'm a worker!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

modify WorkersClass

```
public class WorkersClass {
  protected class Worker implements Employable {

    public Worker(){}

    @Override
    public void work() {
        System.out.println("Hello, I'm a worker!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Correct answer. But why ?

Comment: implicit default constructor visibility is the same as the class visibility, so in this class case, it would have been "protected". And Third is extending WorkerClass, not Worker

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment your answer, however, IT IS A VISIBILIY PROBLEM.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Third` class inherits `WorkersClass` and **not** `Worker`.

Java does not really consider inner classes, it is a simple hack introduced in Java 1.1. The compiler generates class `Worker` "outside" of class `WorkersClass`, but in the same package.
That's why, in order to implement a new `Worker` instance from a `Third` method, you need to add a public constructor to `Worker`:

```
protected class Worker implements Employable {

  public Worker(){
  }

  @Override
  public void work() {
    System.out.println("Hello, I'm a worker!");
  }
}
```